# Запоминание последовательности открытия меню в BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, bottom-navigation-view

Мне нужно чтобы приложение запоминало последовательность открытия меню в `BottomNavigationView` то есть как в VK и Instagram. После того как я по переходил по разным меню, при нажатии `OnBackPressed` оно возвращается в той же последовательности.

У меня же, в каком бы меню я не находился, после нажатия `OnBackPressed` приложение закрывается.

Comment: Вам надо вручную сохранять последовательность открытых экранов, которые должны добавляться в стэк фрагментов.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Есть какой-нибудь пример как это сделать?

Comment: В открытых исходниках не видел... Там, в общем, не сильно сложно. По идее даже должно быть достаточно просто в стэк фрагменты добавлять. Т.е., вроде, можно одной строкой задачу решить.

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы воплотить задуманное нужно использовать `Backstack`, нашёл хороший пример с использованием, [Вот ссылка](https://github.com/JetradarMobile/android-multibackstack)

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]